# Problems with custom scripted YouTube player on Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, safari, youtube

Below is the code I use for nice YouTube video effect on http://tinyurl.com/caa4bsb
 and it works on all browsers except Safari and I simply can't see what the problem is.

If it's impossible or very hard to fix in Safari, then how do I set HTML to be displayed if browser is Safari? (I would simply use normal non-auto-playing video for Safari without overlaying button for sound).

```
<button type="button" id="clicktheplayer" onclick="playlongmovie();"></button>
<div id="ytplayer" style="width:399px; height:225px">
    <p>You will need Flash 8 or better to view this content.</p>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var params = {
        allowScriptAccess: "always",
        'wmode': 'opaque'
    };
    swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/v/ryTH6Ta3qSY?enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer&autoplay=1&rel=0", "ytplayer", "399px", "225px", "8", null, null, params);

    function onYouTubePlayerReady() {
        var ytplayer = document.getElementById("ytplayer");
        ytplayer.mute();
    }

    function playlongmovie() {
        var ytplayer = document.getElementById("ytplayer");
        ytplayer.unMute();
        ytplayer.seekTo(0, true);
        $("#clicktheplayer").hide();
    }
</script>
```